# Displaying all possible combinations of alphabets from a dataset for a given input number

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

What I am trying to achieve is to get the combination of alphabets from a given input number. For eg. if I give an input of 111, the output should be `['AAA','KA','AK']`. If the input is  1111, the output should be `['AAAA','KAA','AKA','AAK','KK']`. 
The partial working code is as follows where I get `['K','K']` for the input 111:

```
    <html>
<head>
    <h1>Javascript</h1>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var dataset =   
        {A:'1',B:'2',C:'3',D:'4',E:'5',F:'6',G:'7',H:'8',I:'9',
       J:'10',K:'11',L:'12',M:'13',N:'14',O:'15',P:'16',Q:'17',R:'18',
        S:'19',T:'20',U:'21',V:'22',W:'23',X:'24',Y:'25',Z:'26'};

        var arr = [];
        var z;  
        var result = [];

        var find = function(input){
            for(var key in dataset) {
                if(dataset[key] === input) {
                    return key;
                }
            }
        }

        var foo = function(x){
            z = x.toString();

            for(var i=0;i<z.length;i++){
                arr.push(z.charAt(i));
            }


            for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
                if(arr[i]+arr[i+1] <= 26){
                    var returnedkey = find(arr[i]+arr[i+1]);
                    result.push(returnedkey);
                }               
            }

        }

        foo(111);
        console.log(arr);
        console.log(result);

    </script>
</body>
```

I am confused how to proceed further and which is the correct method,
Thanks in advance!

Comment: related to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/7001/generating-all-combinations-of-an-array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This proposal uses an object for look up and a recusion for the iteration over the string.

> Example of `getCombination('1111')` with the call of `c()`
>
> First iterate over a single character and then iterate over two characters, if possible.
>
> ```
> left right  letter result
> ---- -----  ------ -----
> 1111         one   
>  111  A      one   
>   11  AA     one   
>    1  AAA    one   
>       AAAA   one   AAAA
>   11  AA     one   
>       AAK    two   AAK
>  111  A      one   
>    1  AK     two   
>       AKA    one   AKA
>   11  K      two   
>    1  KA     one   
>       KAA    one   KAA
>   11  K      two   
>       KK     two   KK
> ```

```js
function getCombination(s) {
    function c(left, right) {
        if (!left) {
            result.push(right);
            return;
        }
        // checks if the first character of left is in the letter object
        // then call c without the first letter of left
        // and right with the letter from the letter object of the first character
        letters[left[0]] && c(left.substring(1), right + letters[left[0]]);

        // it is basically the same as above, but with two characters
        left.length > 1 && letters[left.substring(0, 2)] && c(left.substring(2), right + letters[left.substring(0, 2)]);
    }

    var letters = { 1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'C', 4: 'D', 5: 'E', 6: 'F', 7: 'G', 8: 'H', 9: 'I', 10: 'J', 11: 'K', 12: 'L', 13: 'M', 14: 'N', 15: 'O', 16: 'P', 17: 'q', 18: 'R', 19: 'S', 20: 'T', 21: 'U', 22: 'V', 23: 'W', 24: 'X', 25: 'Y', 26: 'Z' },
        result = [];

    c(s, '');
    return result;
}

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(getCombination('1111'), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(getCombination('1011121314'), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: What does `letters[left[0]] && c(left.substring(1), right + letters[left[0]]);` do? I mean I don't know what it will exactly do. Could you please explain it?

Comment: I tried the solution, it works as expected but I didn't really understand what do these lines do letters[left[0]] && c(left.substring(1), right + letters[left[0]]);
        left.length > 1 && letters[left.substring(0, 2)] && c(left.substring(2), right + letters[left.substring(0, 2)]);

Comment: this `letters[left[0]]` cheks if the first letter is in the object and if so, `c` is called with the rest of left and and with one letter added to right.

Comment: Great explanation, got it! Thanks @NinaScholz